# TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in while statement

Tags: python, sys

I am getting TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '**getitem**' for my while statement below. I am not sure what the problem  is in this case. I am using sys in the code

```
s1P = 4.51775*10.0**16.0
ii= 1 
while s1P[ii-1] > 0.0
    sys.stdout.write('\rstep={0}'.format(ii))
    sys.stdout.flush()

    Rad = s1r[ii-1]+delrms1[ii-1]*delm
    Mas = s1m[ii-1]*[i]
    Pres = s1P[ii-1]+delPms1[ii-1]*delm
    lPres = np.log10(Pres)
    Temp = s1T[ii-1]+delTms1[ii-1]*delm
    lTemp = np.log10(Temp)
    Lum = s1L[ii-1]+deLms1[ii-1]*delm

    Rho = (Pres - 1.0/3.0*a*Temp**4.0)*mu/(NA*k*Temp)
    lRho = np.log10(Rho)
    lR = np.log10(10.0**lRho/(10.0**Temp/10.0**6)**3.0)
    lK = interpolate.bisplev(lTemp,lR,tck)
    K = 10.0**lK
    T_n = Temp/(10.0**9.0)
    epp = 2.4*10.0**4.0*(Rho*X**2.0/T_n**(2.0/3.0))*np.exp(-3.38/T_n**(1.0/3.0))
    ecno = 4.4*10.0**25.0*(Rho*X*Z/T_n**(2.0/3.0))*np.exp(-15.228/T_n**(1.0/3.0))
    eta = 5.0*10.0**8.0*(Rho**2.0*Y**3.0/T_n**3.0)*np.exp(-4.4/T_n)
    ec = epp+ecno+eta
    Bt = NA*k*Rhoc*T_n/(Pres*mu)
    Gam2 =(32.0-24.0*Bt-3.0*Bt**2.0)/(24.0-18.0*Bt-3.0*Bt**2.0)
    drm =  1.0/(4.0*np.pi*Rad**2.0*Rho)
    dPm = -G*Mas*1.99*10.0**33.0/(4.0*np.pi*Rad**4.0)
    dLm = eg

    Term1 = 16.0*np.pi*a*c*G/(3.0*K)
    Term2 = (1.0-1.0/Gam2)
    Term3 = Temp**4.0*(Mas*1.99*10.0**33.0)/Pres
    Tal = Term1+Term2+Term3
    CR = Lum/Tal
    dTrm = -3.0*s1K*s1L/(64.0*np.pi**2.0*a*c*s1r**4.0*s1T**3.0)
    dTcm = -(1.0-1.0/s1gam2)*(G*s1m*1.99*10.0**33.0*s1T/(4.0*np.pi*s1r**4.0*s1P))
    dTm = np.where(Lum > Tal,  dTcm, dTrm)

    sys.stdout.write('\n')
    s1m.append(Mas)
    s1r.append(Rad)
    s1L.append(Lum)
    r_c.append(CR)
    s1T.append(Temp)
    logs1T.append(lTemp)
    s1P.append(Pres)
    logs1P.append(lPres)
    s1rho.append(Rho)
    logs1rho.append(lRho)
    logs1K.append(lK)
    slK.append(K)
    s1eg.append(ec)
    s1gam2.append(Gam2)
    delrms1.append(drm)
    delPms1.append(dPm)
    delLms1.append(dLm)
    delTm1.append(dTm)
    ii = ii+1

sys.stdout.write('\n')

s1m=s1m[:-1]
s1r=s1r[:-1]
s1L=s1L[:-1]
r_c=r_c[:-1]
s1T=s1T[:-1]
logs1T=logs1T[:-1]
s1P=s1P[:-1]
logs1P=logs1P[:-1]
s1rho=s1rho[:-1]
logs1rho=logs1K[:-1]
logs1K=logs1K[:-1]
slK=s1K[:-1]
s1eg=s1eg[:-1]
s1gam2=s1gam2[:-1]
delrms1=delrms1[:-1]
delPms1=delPms1[:-1]
delLms1=delLms1[:-1]
delTm1=delTm1[:-1]
```

Could still be a problem from appending the outputs of my statement?

Comment: Please show us where `s1P` is defined, and please include a complete stack trace.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `while s1P[ii-1] > 0.0`? `s1P` is just a number, it doesn’t make sense to try to access an element (which is what `[ii-1]` does).

Comment: I edited what s1P is. Yes it is a number but this while statement should append new values for slP and stop if SlP > 0.0. At least, that is what I am aiming for.

Comment: Do you want `s1P` to be a single number or a list of numbers? It can’t be both at once.

Comment: It needs to be a list of numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `s1P` is supposed to be a *list* of numbers then you need to initialize it like

```
s1P = [4.51775*10.0**16.0]
```

instead of `s1P = 4.51775*10.0**16.0`, which will make it a single number.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to initialized the value into a list. The error is gone now.