# 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__' Python error

Tags: python

When I run the code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Initial conditions

def f_func(eta,y_in):
    y_out = np.zeros(3)
    y_out[0] = y_in[1]
    y_out[1] = y_in[2]
    y_out[2] = -y_in[0]*y_in[2]/2
    return y_out

eta = np.linspace(0,8,100)
X0 = [0,0,0.33206]
X = odeint(f_func,X0,eta)
```

I get the error

```
 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

When I run the following MATLAB program, everything works OK. The MATLAB function ode45 is equivalent to Pythons' odeint.

main program:

```
clear

global beta
beta = 1;

initial_value = [0,0,1.2322];
eta = linspace(0,4,100)
[x_out, y_out] = ode45(@falkner_skan,eta,initial_value);

plot(x_out,y_out(:,2))
```

falkner_skan function:

```
function y_out = falkner_skan(x,y_in)

global beta

y_out(1,1) = y_in(2);
y_out(2,1) = y_in(3);
y_out(3,1) = -y_in(1)*y_in(3) - beta*(1-y_in(2)^2);

end
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091109/float-object-has-no-attribute-getitem) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500021/typeerror-float-object-has-no-attribute-getitem-in-while-statement) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500021/typeerror-float-object-has-no-attribute-getitem-in-while-statement) thread does not seem to give me any guidance.

Comment: please provide full traceback.

Comment: Have you checked what type `y_in` has?

Comment: The index operator `[]` calls get item. Floats do not support indexing. You are trying to do something like `1.2[3]` You are probably calling `f_func` with a float in `y_in`

Comment: also check `y_in`'s length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as though `y_in` is not a list but a float value. The error rises because you're trying to get an item with `obj[x]` of an object which doesn't support it.

Looking at the [documentation for odeint](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) it says that the input function should take two arguments, the first being your data object and the second should be a float. Your implementation of `f_func` is therefore wrong.

Comment: I updated the question with the remainder of the code. 'y_in' has not yet been defined and this is not necessary for the use of the 'odeint' function

Comment: @JackTaylor Ran your code and added a print statement in the f_func function. y_in is indeed a float and not an int.

Comment: callable(y, t0, ...)
Computes the derivative of y at t0.
<<
This is what the documentation says about how func should be defined. y and t are both floats.

Comment: Thank you @materik . what might a solution be?

Comment: I'm not sure of the mathematics you want to perform on the object but try using the argument that you have named `eta` instead of `y_in`. `eta` is an array.

Comment: @JackTaylor does that make sense?

Comment: It does make sense but I'm not really sure what to do. I updated the question with MATLAB code using the ode45 function, this code works! Not sure if you are familiar with MATLAB.

Comment: yes, i'm familiar with MATLAB. the difference between the MATLAB function and the python function is the arguments of the f_func, python have them the other way around, change your f_func definition to f_func(y_in, eta): and it should work I think!

Comment: Great! Mind marking the answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 1):

NumPy has float 64 object which has item() function, np.float64(10.5).item()

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. According to [documentation for odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html), in f_func(eta,y_in), change the order of eta and y_in, i.e. write it as f_func(y_in, eta) or set the argument *tfirst* to be *True*.