# TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to pass a dataframe to a function and compute mean and std dev from different columns of the dataframe. When I execute each line of the function step by step (without writing a function as such) it works fine. However, when I try to write a function to compute, I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This is my code:

```
def computeBias(data):        

    meandata = np.array(data['mean'])
    sddata = np.array(data.sd)
    ni = np.array(data.numSamples)      

    mean = np.average(meandata, weights=ni)
    pooled_sd = np.sqrt((np.sum(np.multiply((ni - 1), np.array(sddata)**2)))/(np.sum(ni) - 1))

    return mean, pooled_sd


mean,sd = df.apply(computeBias)
```

This is sample data:

```
id           type             mean           sd              numSamples
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             33              -0.43          0.40               101
2             23              -0.76          0.1                100
3             33               0.89          0.56               101
4             45               1.4           0.9                100
```

This is the full error traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-f4dc392140dd> in <module>()
----> 1 mean,sd = df.apply(computeBias)

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2353             else:
   2354                 values = self.asobject
-> 2355                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2356 
   2357         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer (pandas\_libs\lib.c:66440)()

<ipython-input-133-2af38e3e29f0> in computeBias(data)
      1 def computeBias(data):
      2 
----> 3     meandata = np.array(data['mean'])
      4     sddata = np.array(data.sd)
      5     ni = np.array(data.numSamples)

TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Does anyone know of any workaround? TIA!

Comment: Please edit in the full error traceback

Comment: @OferSadan: Done.

Comment: Did you google the error?  There are quite a few https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950113/float-object-has-no-attribute-getitem-python-error questions referencing that error.

Comment: What type do you expect `data` to be here? From the error message, it seems to be of type `float`. Make sure you are passing in a dictionary or other type with a `__getitem__` method.

Comment: @gobrewers14: I did. But I really couldn't understand what was going on here. Because when I do the same step by step without calling a function, it works and gives me an output. Not quite sure what is going wrong inside the function.

Comment: meandata = np.array(data['mean'], dtype='f') did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

```
meandata = np.array(data['mean'])
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

`__getitem__` is the method that Python tries to call when you use indexing.  In the marked line that means `data['mean']` is producing the error.  Evidently `data` is a number, a float object.  You can't index a number.

`data['mean']` looks like you are either trying to get an item from a dictionary, or from a dataframe, using a named index.  I won't dig into the rest of your code to determine what you intend.

What you need to do it understand what `data` really it, and what produces it.

---

You are using this in a `df.apply(....)`, and apparently think that it just means

```
computeBias(df)   # or
computeBias(df.data)
```

Rather I suspect the `apply` is iterating, in some dimension, over the dataframe, and passing values or dataseries to your code.  It isn't passing the whole dataframe.

Comment: I figured it was some problem with the apply function. I used apply because I wanted to pass groupedby objects as well to the function. But it doesn't work anyway. So, I am just iterating over groups and computing the statistics by sending the respective columns.